# How to expand MySQL subquery/join to include all rows

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

This query below is perfect in producing the result for `horse_id = 1` ... but I want to do this for all horses in the database. Can anyone share with me how to tweak this query so I can do that?

```
SELECT  figures.entry_id,
        max(figures.beyer)
FROM
        ( SELECT  hrdb_lines.horse_id,
                  hrdb_entries.entry_id,
                  hrdb_lines.beyer
          FROM hrdb_entries
            INNER JOIN hrdb_lines 
                ON hrdb_lines.horse_id = hrdb_entries.horse_id
          WHERE hrdb_lines.horse_id = 1
          ORDER BY hrdb_lines.line_date DESC
          LIMIT 2
        ) as figures
```

Perhaps I'm doing it all wrong too.

Comment: Change your `WHERE hrdb_lines.horse_id = 1` to `GROUP BY hrdb_lines.horse_id` and that should work.

Comment: This changed the result, but the problem is the query I limit to two is used to grab the two most recent results. Doing the "group by" just spits out a random entry_id and max(figures.beyer)... if that make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question, something like this should be close:

```
SELECT
    figures.horse_id,
    figures.entry_id,
    max(figures.beyer)
FROM
    (SELECT
        hrdb_lines.horse_id,
        hrdb_entries.entry_id,
        hrdb_lines.beyer
    FROM hrdb_entries
        INNER JOIN hrdb_lines ON hrdb_lines.horse_id = hrdb_entries.horse_id
    ORDER BY hrdb_lines.line_date DESC
    ) as figures
GROUP BY figures.horse_id
```

One option to limit the MAX to just the most recent 2 beyer fields is to add a row number to the results and only include rows 1 and 2.

```
SELECT
    figures.horse_id,
    figures.entry_id,
    max(figures.beyer)
FROM
    (SELECT
        @rn:=if(@prev_horse_id=horse_id,@rn+1,1) rn,
        hrdb_lines.horse_id,
        hrdb_entries.entry_id,
        hrdb_lines.beyer,
        @prev_horse_id:=hrdb_lines.horse_id
    FROM hrdb_entries
        INNER JOIN hrdb_lines ON hrdb_lines.horse_id = hrdb_entries.horse_id
        INNER JOIN (SELECT @rn:=0) r
    ORDER BY hrdb_lines.horse_id, hrdb_lines.line_date DESC
    ) as figures
WHERE rn <= 2
GROUP BY figures.horse_id
```

Comment: This is definitely closer. I should have been clearer but the "limit" is to basically grab the higher beyer from the two most recent lines. This particularly query gives me the max for all of the lines in the database (beyond the two most recent).

Comment: @TravisVOX -- see edits above.  I've introduced a row number variable which should produce the results you're looking for (again, if I'm understanding).  Hope this helps.

Comment: I implemented your suggestion but it still isn't limited the "max" to the two lines the where field has limited it to? If I change the `WHERE rn <= 2` it doesn't change the result either (except when set to zero).

Comment: @TravisVOX -- I wrote the code too fast -- the If statement should be: if(@prev_horse_id=horse_id,@rn+1,1) and added horse_id to the ORDER BY.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following would generate the desired results:

```
SELECT `entry_id`, `beyer`
FROM (SELECT hrdb_entries.entry_id,
        MAX( hrdb_lines.beyer )
    FROM hrdb_entries
    INNER JOIN hrdb_lines 
        ON hrdb_lines.horse_id = hrdb_entries.horse_id
    GROUP BY hrdb_lines.horse_id
    ORDER BY hrdb_lines.line_date DESC
    ) AS figures
```